# Tkinter module - taskbar not showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Does anyone know why it will not show the taskbar in my code. I am trying to get the top to say Exit and information in the file drop down menu. I am kind of new to tkinter and i just need a bit of help please. Also if you have any suggestions on how to improve it, i would really appreciate it!

My code is below:

```
from time import sleep
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk, Tk

root = Tk()

class GUI():

    def taskbar(self):

        menu = Menu(root)
        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.exit_GUI)
        file.add_command(label = "Information", command=self.info_popup)        

   def Main_Menu(self):

        topFrame = Frame(root)
        topFrame.pack()
        bottomFrame = Frame(root)
        bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        Income_button = Button(topFrame, text="Enter your incomes", command=self.Income)
        Expense_button = Button(topFrame, text="Enter your expenses", command=self.Expense)
        Total_button = Button(bottomFrame, text="View Results", command=self.Total)
        Income_button.pack()
        Expense_button.pack()
        Total_button.pack()

    def Income(self):
        pass

    def Expense(self):
        pass

    def Total(self):
        pass

    def exit_GUI(self):
        exit()

    def info_popup(self):
        pass

g = GUI()
g.taskbar()
g.Main_Menu()
g.Income()
g.Expense()
g.Total()
g.info_popup()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You forgot the `root.config(menu=menu)` to tell the window to actually use your menubar.

Comment: @jasonharper didn't work, it said menu is not defined

Comment: You need to do it at a point where `menu` actually is defined, then.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `taskbar` function to:

```
def taskbar(self):

    menu = Menu(root)
    file = Menu(menu)
    file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.exit_GUI)
    file.add_command(label = "Information", command=self.info_popup) 
    root.config(menu=file)
```

This will tell the window to use the menubar.

Comment: it stopped giving me the error but it still didn't show up when the script is run